# Logging Scheduled Process Over Time

Tags: .net, database-design, architecture, logging

We have implemented a process in one of the systems where it's scheduled to run hourly. The process should run over some imported records from a legacy system, do some qualification changes, and update the records status and qualification notes.

The following is some facts regarding this process:

1. The process can execute on 1000 records daily.
2. Qualifying a single record involves a complex logic path. At some point, we will need to debug and know how a specific record was qualified or unqualified. Which path of logic it takes to get qualified or unqualified.

I would like to know:

1. If there is any design pattern or architecture can be used to apply an efficient logging for these kind of scheduled processes.
2. Which information is considered essential to be logged when implementing our logging mechanism for this process?
3. Which is better in this case: store the log in a database or file system? If a database logging is better, is there any preferred design?

I would appreciate if there is any articles or references that can provide more details about the best practice in logging scheduled processes actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer your question, I'd need to know what the purpose of the logs is. I'm going to make some guesses, but if you could extend your question, that would help.

Typically, there are 2 reasons to include logging in an application.

**Application monitoring**

With these unattended processes, you need to be sure they are still running, and that someone is notified if they don't. Of course, this has a catch-22 - if the application doesn't start, how can it log anything?

Most IT departments have a monitoring tool, which allows them to keep an eye on their systems from afar - Microsoft has [Operations Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/operations-manager.aspx). So, your "heart beat" logs should play nice with the monitoring tool; the best place for this kind of logging would be the Windows Event Log. The event log doesn't die on you (as a database might), can be read from other machines without having to set up file shares etc., and integrates out of the box with all kinds of monitoring tools.

Heart beat monitoring might include:

- Job started.
- Job finished, x records processed, y qualified, z unqualified
- Exceptions and errors

Your monitoring tool can then keep an eye on the job, and make sure that "x, y and z" are within expected boundaries.

Log exceptions to the event log too - that way, your monitoring tool can tell you when things have gone wrong without you having to parse log files every day.

**Debugging**

Of course, you will also want to be able investigate what happens when things go wrong. This would typically not go into the event log - debug logs can contain sensitive information, and the operations team rarely have any use for them.

I usually write debug logs to disk, using a rolling appender to make sure they don't consume too much disk space.

I usually log to these files at "INFO" level, with an option to switch to DEBUG through configuration.

What you log is determined largely by the application design. You should definitely record "input" data, so a developer can re-run the code with the input that you're trying to debug. If the process requires external data to run, also log that data (e.g. if you use a web service to get information which determines the outcome). I wouldn't record every step in the decision tree at "INFO" level - it's too verbose, and hard to trace.

**Audit**

If you have audit requirements, the Event log is the appropriate location - you can set security so that the data cannot be manipulated by unauthorised staff.

I'm assuming you're using one of the many logging frameworks already - Log4Net is my favourite.

In the comments, you mention that the primary purpose for the logging requirement is to be able to track and explain the outcome of the process. I wouldn't call that "logging" to be honest - it sounds like a first class requirement from the business domain, whereas logging is usually done to satisfy technical requirements. Log files are intended for technical people, and usually stay on the (secure) machine on which the jobs run - your requirement sounds like it is customer facing.

I would re-visit the application design, and see what the best way is for satisfying the business requirement. There are a number of design patterns that might help - ["Chain of responsibility"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) is a neat way of modeling this kind of decision tree, and you could easily extend it to include a log of the chain.

Comment: The main purpose of logs is to clarify the reason behind qualifying the records. In other words, why and how the qualification goes through the complex logic/flow and get qualified. Our customers always need a clarification of why some claim got unqualified for example. As not all the logic is visible to the end user, at the some point we need to justify the reason to the end user and this is not possible unless I have an efficient logging design, or at least I think so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One of my main challenges, is to have a good way to log the "qualification path", i.e. which path the qualification process takes to qualify a record. I'm totally confused as I don't know how such thing could be logged and in the same time be useful for me to "quickly" justify a good answer to the end user when asking about who some record got qualified or unqualified.

Answer (score 1):

In the same situation I would log the following:

- Schedule job started
- How many records the scheduled job found required processing
- Debug information on the processing of each record
- Statistics information on how many records were processed and the result of the processing

Generally this type of logging is done to file. The problem with logging to database is that if the database goes down, your logging stops.